# Beizer Curve does not extrude to form a CAD-like solid

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

I am trying to make this [chair](https://www.fredericia.com/products/by-designer-b%C3%B8rge-mogensen/s%C3%B8borg-wood-base-1.aspx) with Blender's bezier curves and I achieved this outline.
[image: Chair].

But neither the *Solidify* modifier neither the *Extrude* option are helping.

[Blender File](https://upload.disroot.org/r/hJT8s5MQ#fI3J3/eIUISXf/AQHUu40SPOpmvtgE00HOtr/LTU0A8=)

Answer (score 2):

You have two issues with your chair.

1. First on is wrong curve direction. Blender curves always extrude in the local $Z$ axis, but your curve is vertically aligned and bidimensional along the $YZ$ plane, so the extrusion remain in-plane with your 2D shape yielding inscrutable results.
2. Second problem is your curve has an offset value of $1.0$, which will make the surfaces extruded be offset one unit from the actual curve geometry. At the chair scale this will give unrecognizable results.

### How to fix.

1. Either rotate the curve $90^o$ along the global $Y$ axis in *Edit Mode*, then rotate the curve back up by $-90^o$ in *Object Mode*, or rotate the curve $90^o$ along the global $Y$ axis in *Object Mode*, apply the rotation with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>A</kbd>, then rotate it back up by rotating the curve $-90^o$ along the global $Y$ axis in *Object Mode*.
2. Set the *Offset* to $0.0$ iin the *Properties Window > Object Data (Curve) > Geometry > Offset*.

[image]

Optionally set the cure to *2D* and *Fill Mode* to *Both*